# Mysql OUTER JOIN syntax

Tags: mysql

My tables are as follow

```
productsA : name,price

productsB : name,date,price,...
```

At the moment, productsB contains a subset of productsA, with today's date (trying to make things simple, I know the info I'm missing, and will be able to sort out the rest).

I want to select all products from products A if there's no records in productsB for today's date. For simplification let's say date='2014-04-15' (fixed).

I tried :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM productsA AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN productsB as b on a.name = b.name AND b.date != '2014-04-15'
```

But it doesn't work...

I tried to simplify, and remove the date parameter, but I end up with the whole productsA table, no matter how I try :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM productsA AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN productsB AS b ON a.name = b.name
```

It must be simple, yet I'm stuck (I spared you all the errored attempts)... Anyone, help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find those in `a` with no related record in `b`, principally you need to be looking for `NULL` values with a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  productsA AS a
  /* Your joining condition was almost correct- you need records equaling the date... */
  LEFT JOIN productsB AS b ON a.name = b.name AND b.date = '2014-04-15'
WHERE
  /* NULL returned for b means no match */
  b.name IS NULL
```

Note: with the correct `DATE` type on that column you could also use `b.date = CURDATE()` in the `ON` clause...

Comment: Yes, I oversimplified the question to get the info I really needed. It will of course be a DATE field in my real db ;)

Comment: @xShirase I'm going to edit my answer to use the right date format for MySQL then. I can't bear looking at a `m/d/yy` date string...

Comment: haha ok then, I'll edit my question. Thanks for your detailed right answer, i'm sure it'll help more than just me!